# Shining text and brightness around the text with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to make effects like the in the images, with just CSS?

It would be sad to lose all precious SEO because of images replacing text.

**Brightness around the text**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bISVC.png

**Shining text**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9ojb.jpg

I first thought of shadows and stuff but I can't figure anything out...

Comment: Here's a tutorial that might help http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-glowing-link-effect/

Comment: Googled the title of the question, [first result](http://line25.com/articles/using-css-text-shadow-to-create-cool-text-effects)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a shadow like this : `text-shadow: 0 0 3px #0000FF;`

Answer (score 0):

These effects are achieved working with multiple shadows layering colors over a dark background. 
Here is an example:

```css
.glow{
      font-family: Sans-serif;
      font-size: 3rem;
      background: black;
      color: white;
      padding: 80px;
      text-shadow:
                  1px 1px 0px gold,
                  -3px -0 25px red,
                  3px 0px 3px white,
                  0px 0px 15px white,
                  15px 10px 10px black,
                  0 0 40px orangered,
                  0 0 40px orangered,
                  0 0 60px orangered,
                  0 0 80px orangered,
                  0 0 80px orangered,
                  0 0 100px orangered,
                  0 0 150px orangered;
       }
```

```html
<h1 class="glow">Glowing CSS only</h1>
```